# Options for syncing a caldav server with Outlook users?

Tags: outlook, webdav, icalendar, caldav

We've got an (in-house developed) calendaring system that support calDav/ical.  We are looking for a way for Outlook users to be able to sync with our system.  This solution needs to be able to allow outlook users to perform all the CRUD operations in outlook, and have them sync'd up with our system via caldav.  (That is, read-only won't work).

I think this product http://funambol.com/ will do it, but it seems maybe a bit of overkill, and the website just looks like its going to be expensive.

Any other solutions out there?  Ideas?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I guess [funambol](http://funambol.com/) is the only real solution.

[sarc]'Course, you could build it yourself.  That should only take a weekend or two.[/sarc]

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is use another tool to use calendar, I'm now using eM Client http://www.emclient.com/